# The "two cups of chino" joke

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, friends

In the *Friends* episode "The One With All The Haste" Chandler approaches Gunther and [says](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season4/419haste.htm):

> Yes, Gunther, can I get two cups of chino, please?

to which Gunther replies:

> Good one.

which suggests that it was a joke.

I understand that it's a wordplay on "cappuccino" and (probably) "chino" trousers, but I don't seem to get the joke.

Could someone explain?

Comment: [Some](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100408211023AAxrA7k) people [genuinely](http://www.adelaidenow.com.au/lifestyle/sa-lifestyle/i-giggle-when-i-hear-people-ask-for-two-cups-of-chino/news-story/a4bc4af1c1347e0eaeb37e43a056ab14) mistake cappuccino for 'cup o' chino'. Chandler is pretending he's one of them, though he's clearly not because he says it jokingly. And Gunther (who has probably heard this before, and is usually grumpy anyway) is not amused.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks! Maybe you could write an answer, so I can accept? The answer given by Dr R Dizzle is somewhat similar, but your explanation is much better.

Comment: I always thought that it was just Gunther being grumpy and "Good One" was just him blowing off Chandler.

Comment: OK, done, but I agree with Dizzle too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some [people](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100408211023AAxrA7k) genuinely [mistake](http://www.adelaidenow.com.au/lifestyle/sa-lifestyle/i-giggle-when-i-hear-people-ask-for-two-cups-of-chino/news-story/a4bc4af1c1347e0eaeb37e43a056ab14) *cappuccino* for *'cup o' chino'*. Chandler is *pretending* he doesn't know that either, though he clearly does because he says it jokingly. And Gunther, who probably heard this before in his profession and is usually grumpy anyway and in no mood for jokes, is just not amused (note his expression\tone).

Answer (score 1):

"Cups of chino" sounds a lot like "cappuccino". I think that's the full extent of the joke - it's Gunther's sarcastic reply that is the real punchline.